# A way to clear react browser history?

Tags: reactjs

Using react's history/createBrowserHistory and was wondering if there was a way to clear the entire history. Wanted to clear the entire history when a user logs out of an application (could be up to the point when history was first used in the app).  I've looked [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/modules/createBrowserHistory.js) but don't see a function to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the documentation fails to explain the functionality I need, I immediately jump to the unit tests. Most (good) unit tests are able to clean any state that was modified from the last. A good test for this library would have to clean the browser history before every test. I should be the first thing we see. As I suspected, the [first test suite](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/modules/__tests__/BrowserHistory-test.js#L11) appears to be clearing something on line #11.

```
window.history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
```

However, this does not do what you want. It actually replaces the current state object of the url you are currently on. It looks like the functionality you are looking for has been denied and argued against. But Why? Because it's not very nice to remove the users browser history. It has been argued that this functionality is a security issue. *"But I want to allow users to press the back button, but ensure history is not tracked and I want it now!* - This is actually possible with a little hack. You'll most likely have to make your own library for this, because it's generally considered bad practice to disable the back button.

If your users really want it, I guess you could do something like this, but it might stop working in case chrome decides this is against the rules.

```
// manage your own history instead of letting the browser do it
const url_history = [];

// hack to disable the back button
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  // do not disable back button if the array is empty
  var last = url_history.pop();
  if (last) {
    history.pushState(last.state, last.name, last.url);
  }
});

function push_url(state, name, url) {
  url_history.push({
    state: state,
    name: name,
    url: url
  });
  history.pushState(state, name, 'url');
}

// add initial history entry
history.pushState(null, null, '/');
```

Comment: If you find out this code doesn't work on certain browsers, please let me know!

Comment: Didn't know removing history was opposed.  I can see their viewpoint.  If this is the case I'll look for other alternatives to clearing the history.  Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 2):

In reactJS you should use browserHistory for this purpose. This takes care of you histories and you dont need to implement those functions on your own.

browserHistory has 2 methods push() and replace() which do the same functions

HTML5 history API provide two methods to `Adding and modifying history entries`.

`pushState()` : back state preserved
`replaceState()` : no back state

Assuming you are using `react-router`.
So, on your Component use

```
this.props.history.replaceState('your new state')
```

read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: replace() doesn't seem to work for me.  Even when I call it, I can still press the back button and it will go back to all the pages I've visited in the app.  I want to remove/clear history.